# Change current location programmatically

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component

How can I programmatically change the current location ?

The `app-location` is on parent element and I want change it from the child element.

here is parent excerpt

```
dom-module(id='test', assetpath='/')
    template
        app-location(route='{{route}}')
        app-route(route='{{route}}', pattern='/:page', data='{{rootData}}', tail='{{rootTail}}')
        ...
        login-page(name='login', route='[[rootTail]]')
        ...
    script.
        Polymer({is: 'test');
```

and the child

```
dom-module(id='login-page')
    template
        div(class='layout horizontal center-justified mh400')
            div(class='layout vertical center-justified')
                form(is='iron-form', id='login-form', method='post', action='/api/auth/login', on-iron-form-response='onResponse')
                    ...
    script.
        Polymer({
            is: 'login-page',
            onResponse: function (event) {
                var resp = event.detail.response;

                if (resp.success) {
                    // Change here the location
                }
            }
        })
```

Sorry by the Jade instead of html but give to understand i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app-location` simply interfaces with the location bar of the browser. It uses `iron-location` internally. There's nothing stopping you from including it in the child element as well. It's role here would be to update the location bar (instead of listening to changes). In your JavaScript, select the element and update its `path`.

The `app-location` in the parent element will detect the change in the location bar and update `route`

```
dom-module(id='login-page')
    template
        app-location
        div(class='layout horizontal center-justified mh400')
            div(class='layout vertical center-justified')
                form(is='iron-form', id='login-form', method='post', action='/api/auth/login', on-iron-form-response='onResponse')
                    ...
    script.
        Polymer({
            is: 'login-page',
            onResponse: function (event) {
                var resp = event.detail.response;

                if (resp.success) {
                    // TODO: Update with your new path
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('app-location').path = '';
                }
            }
        })
```